# Open bootstrap modal from other modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap 4 and AJAX in my project.

In page with 2 models. Inside first modal `(id='#modal-lg')` I have button which must to open second modal `(id='#modal')`. When I click that button it didnt open second modal. It just close first modal. How to fix this problem? Where I did mistake?

**template.html:**

```
{# FIRST MODAL #}
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-lg">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-body">
            <button id="requirement-add-button" data-url="{% url 'project:requirement_add' %}">
               {% trans 'Add New Requirement' %}
            </button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
{# FIRST MODAL #}

{# SECOND MODAL #}
<div class="modal fade" id="modal">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
{# SECOND MODAL #}
```

**js:**

```
$(function () {
    var loadForm = function () {
        var btn = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: btn.attr("data-url"),
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#modal").modal("show");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#modal .modal-content").html(data.html_requirement_form);
            }
        });
    };

    var saveForm = function () {
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr("action"),
            data: form.serialize(),
            type: form.attr("method"),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.form_is_valid) {
                    $("#requirement-table tbody").html(data.html_requirement);
                    $("#modal").modal("hide");
                }
                else {
                    $("#modal .modal-content").html(data.html_requirement_form);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    };

    // CREATE
    $("#requirement-add-button").click(loadForm);
    $("#modal").on("submit", ".js-requirement-add-form", saveForm);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the result of your server-side script (ajax result). But I made a sample proof-of-concept to trigger second modal from first modal. As shown below, it's working fine.

Have you checked the result of your ajax data?
Did you try to `console.log` or debug the result of `data.html_requirement` and/or `data.html_requirement_form` ?

```js
$(function() {
  
  // open 1st modal on load
  $("#modal-lg").modal({ backdrop: "static "});
  
  $("#openFirst").on("click", function(e) {
    $("#modal-lg").modal({ backdrop: "static "});
  });
  
  $("#requirement-add-button").on("click", function(e) {
  
   // hide 1st modal
    $("#modal-lg").modal('hide');
    
    // show 2nd modal
    $("#modal .modal-body").html("SECOND MODAL CONTENT");
    $("#modal").modal({ backdrop: "static "});
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button id="openFirst" class="btn btn-primary">OpenFirst</button>

{# FIRST MODAL #}
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-lg">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-body">
            <button id="requirement-add-button" data-url="{% url 'project:requirement_add' %}">
               {% trans 'Add New Requirement' %}
            </button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
{# FIRST MODAL #}

{# SECOND MODAL #}
<div class="modal fade" id="modal">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
        TEST 2nd MODAL HERE
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
{# SECOND MODAL #}
```

---

**Edit**

Added fiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/Lwdfourp/

```
var loadForm = function (e) {

      var btn = $(this);
      $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
          // url: btn.attr("data-url"),
          url: '/echo/json/', // JSFIDDLE TEST URL
          data: {
            delay: 2,
            json: JSON.stringify({
                field1: "value1",
              html_requirement_form: "<input name='test-input' />"
            })
          },
          success: function (data) {

            // hide 1st modal
                    $("#modal-lg").modal('hide');

            // show 2nd modal and add result
            $("#modal").modal('show');
            $("#modal .modal-body").html(
                "URL: " + btn.data("url") + "<br/>" + 
              "CONTENT : " + data.html_requirement_form
            );
          }
      });

  };
```

Comment: Hello! I am little bit comfused cause dont know how to modify my code with your code. Can you give me one more advice. Let me try to explain my current code little bit to you. When user click button (`id="requirement-add-button"`) I want to run the `loadForm` function. This function just show second modal and inside `.modal-content` block put form. When user submit second modal I want to save data from this form. I tested this ajax with other my modal. It works.